# Photoshop - change colors of image

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color

I am very new at photoshop and I am not sure if I have chosen the correct title for the question but I'll give you an example so hopefully that will do it. So basically I am trying to blend one image into another and I've used mask and everything to cut edges but it still doesn't look very authentic and I would like to know if there is a way to paint the image in colours similar to those of the background so that it blends easily. This is what I have for the moment:

[image]

I would like for the image on top to be brownish like the old paper on the background instead of gray. Is that possible? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Change the gray image layer blending mode to: Luminosity.

Answer (score 1):

Since it appears to be just a black and white image I'd suggest changing the layer style to Linear Burn or Color Burn and playing with the opacity. That ought to give it a brownish color that blends into the brown background.

Answer (score 1):

If it's an exact match you're going for, you could try the 'Match Color' option:

- Have your foreground and background in separate files, both open.
- With the foreground active, choose 'Image' > 'Adjustments' > 'Match Color...'.
- At the bottom of the dialog box, choose your background file as the 'Source'.
- Click 'OK'.
- Re-add your foreground layer into your backgroung file.

Photoshop will use only the colours in your background image to display the foreground image. The result is rather dependent upon the background's color range. You might want to fade the effect a little ('Edit' > 'Fade Match Color' or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd>) or tweak it with some adjustment layers like 'Curves'.

Answer (score 0):

You could try what @Mordred suggests.

You could also choose the grayscale layer, chose `image -> adjustment -> black and white` (yes, again!) and check the `Tint` checkbox. Then you play around with giving it the tint of your choice.

Another option is to make the grayscale layer more transparent. This will of course give it less of a contrast, but as far as I understand, that is what you are looking for.

Yet another, is to go to `image -> adjustment -> curves` and play around there.

...I suggest you try one at a time, create a duplicate layer for each, and do not combine these suggestions. I will get messy :)